# Deleting application content from storage in Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I'm currently having trouble properly uninstalling a Windows Phone app. The application is ported to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. My problem is that whenever I uninstall the application, its file storage content (some maps and data) don't actually get removed and on reinstalling the application returns to the initial state (before uninstall).

- Is this an intended behavior or just a bug / limit in Windows Phone 10 (I'm running the Insider Preview of course) ?
- If it's not a Windows limit / bug, then how do I actually remove all storage content on uninstalling the app (I'm thinking of sth like Android's Clear Data / Clear Cache options for each app) ?

Any suggestions will be well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you storing the files and data? What API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you uninstalling the application?

Can you browse through the file system using softwares like "IsoStoreSpy"? you can even uninstall application using IsoStoreSpy or even delete the file/folder data manually. Not sure if the Application Settings data is removed in your case?

Also make sure to kill the application instance before uninstalling or accessing through ISoStoreSPy.(not running in background)

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to exactly. I'm just doing a regular uninstall: Long tap on the application -> Uninstall